# How to set "Amazon Corretto Java" as default instead of Oracle Java

Tags: java, java-8, java-11, java-17, corretto

I have installed Oracle Java 17 and Amazon Corretto 17 in linux server. It is picking default as "Oracle Java" but i need Amazon corretto Java to be default. Please help me on this

i tried bellow amazon link but no luck
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-11-ug/generic-linux-install.html

Comment: You'll need to provide much more information. What type of Linux server is it? Are you using rpm or apt? When you said "it is picking default" what do you mean by "it"? Different things might be picking different versions by default. What is in your PATH variable? Is there a /usr/bin/java and what does it link to? Have you tried `update-alternatives`?